Как перехватить просроченный access токен в конвейере обработки запросов, до того как клиенту будет отправлена 401?
Есть middleware, который должен перехватывать исключение SecurityTokenExpiredException, и обновлять access токен, если это возможно. Но в режиме отладки видно, что до блока catch дело не доходит. В Postman прилетает 401 и сообщение:

"Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The token expired at
'11/24/2024 19:06:53'""

В конвейер обработки добавляю middleware в следующем порядке:
app.UseMiddleware<RefreshTokenExceptionHandler>();
app.UseAuthorization();

Сам класс обработчика:
public class RefreshTokenExceptionHandler 
{
    private readonly ITokenService tokenService;
    private readonly IServiceProvider serviceProvider;
private readonly RequestDelegate Next;
public RefreshTokenExceptionHandler(RequestDelegate next, ITokenService tokenService, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    this.tokenService = tokenService;
    this.serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    Next = next;
}



public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
    try
    {
        await Next(context);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (ex is SecurityTokenExpiredException)
        {
            // Токен доступа истек. Пробуем обновить.
            await HandleRefreshTokenAsync(context);
        }
        else
        {
            // Передать исключение вниз по конвейеру обработки.
            throw;
        }
    }
}


Видим, что следующим в конвейере идет Authorization, то есть по идее все верно...
Были мысли, что эту задачу следует решать не добавлением компонента в контейнер, а добавлением обработчика 401, и я понятия не имею, что из этого является корректным подходом. Прошу помощи

На кой чёрт вы пытаетесь обновить токен на бекенде и как это вообще должно работать-то?

@PavelMayorov а почему не на бэкенде? Лучшей практикой считается следить за временем истечения токена на клиенте? Предполагалось, что схема работы следующая: с клиента в каждом запросе приходит a и r токены, пробуем авторизовать и, если токен истек, то обновляем его в моем мидлваре. Выполняем запрос пользователя и к заголовку нашего ответа добавляем обновленный токен. На клиенте следим за наличием заголовка с новым токеном в ответе.

зачем так сложно? Рефреш токен по идее одноразовый и передавать его стоит один раз только, это заодно поможет при MITM атаках и подобных - вы передаете обычный токен пока он работает, как тоько его время истекло или бпекенд флагает токен нерабочим - только тогда отдельным вызовом на клиенте шлете рефреш токен, получаете новый токен аутентификации и продолжаете слать запросы.

то есть решение об использовании рефреш токена должно быть на клиенте, не на сервере.

@tym32167 так действительно проще. Спасибо за ответ!
